# Chain commands in Laravel Artisan Scheduler?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Suppose I have three commands I want to schedule:
'commandA', 'commandB', and 'commandC'

But I don't want to run 'commandB' until 'commandA' is complete and I don't want to run 'commandC' until 'commandB' is complete.

I know I can schedule each to run every five minutes:

```
$schedule->command('commandA')->everyFiveMinutes();
$schedule->command('commandB')->everyFiveMinutes();
$schedule->command('commandC')->everyFiveMinutes();
```

But is it possible to chain them one after the other?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [then(Closure $callback)](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html#method_then) to chain commands:

```
$schedule->command('commandA')->everyFiveMinutes()->then(function() {
    $this->call('commandB');
    $this->call('commandC');
});
```

Comment: Actually that didn't seem to work. First issue was that the $schedule variable was not known within the Closure. Fixed that by using 'use'. 

I would see commandA being executed but commandB and commandC were not executed. 

One way I ended up getting them to run was using $this->call('commandB'); within the Closure.

Comment: @wkm thank you for reply! Please make changes on my answer co I can apply these changes to it.

Comment: @wkm just tested this in my sandbox and amended my answer. 100% working and tested now :)

Comment: Here's the official [docs](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html#method_then) for `->then`