# How can I schedule the pinging of routes within my application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

In my Laravel 5.6 project, I have a couple of routes that perform several complex tasks such as scrapping and database insertions. I've already set up my cronjob to go into my project folder and I've located my Kernel file but I'm stuck on how to invoke calls to various routes.

Which is the best way to do a scheduled task that pings several routes sequentially i.e. one has to complete execution before proceeding to the next one.

Comment: Call the script from the end of the script, simple as that really, chain them, or fork as required to run 2

Comment: Care to provide a simple example of how to call the script in the Kernel file?

Comment: [Example of chaining commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29825558/3585500) using `then` with callbacks.

Comment: Thanks. This ought to help.