# Laravel scheduler chain process calls

Tags: php, laravel, scheduler, laravel-scheduler

I have several processes that I want to chain using the laravel scheduler.

```
<?php

namespace App\Process;

use App\Loggers\Logger;

class UtilsProcess
{
    public function test1()
    {
        Logger::info("Launch 'UtilsProcess::test1' process");
        sleep(5);
        Logger::info("Process 'UtilsProcess::test1' succeedeed");
    }
    public function test2()
    {
        Logger::info("Launch 'UtilsProcess::test2' process");
        sleep(20);
        Logger::info("Process 'UtilsProcess::test2' succeedeed");
    }
    public function test3()
    {
        Logger::info("Launch 'UtilsProcess::test3' process");
        sleep(10);
        Logger::info("Process 'UtilsProcess::test3' succeedeed");
    }
}
```

I tried to reproduce [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825483/chain-commands-in-laravel-artisan-scheduler), in order to have test2 running once test1 is finished and test3 after test2 is finished.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call('App\Process\UtilsProcess@test1')->everyMinute()->name("test1")
        ->then(function(){
            $this->call("App\Process\UtilsProcess@test2")->name("test2");
            $this->call("App\Process\UtilsProcess@test3")->name("test3");
        }
    );
}
```

However after test1 is finished, I'm facing the following error

```
[2023-06-30 07:32:48] local.INFO: Launch 'UtilsProcess::test1' process  
[2023-06-30 07:32:53] local.INFO: Process 'UtilsProcess::test1' succeedeed
[2023-06-30 07:32:53] local.ERROR: The command "AppProcessUtilsProcess@test2" does not exist.
```

I tried several solutions but I can't find a way to have the test2 function being called within the `Closure` callback.

Comment: It might be worth looking at job batching: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#job-batching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to define `test2` and `test3` as commands by creating a file for each under `App\Console\Commands` as follow

```
// File \App\Console\Commands\test2.php

<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Process\UtilsProcess;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class test2 extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'test2';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Test 2';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $utils = new UtilsProcess();
        $utils->test2();
    }
}
```

And then call the commands from `\App\Console\Kernel.php` as follow

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call('App\Process\UtilsProcess@test1')->everyMinute()->name("test1")
        ->then(function(){
            $this->call("test2")->name("test2");
            $this->call("test3")->name("test3");
        }
    );
}
```

I would have preferred to directly call the class method from within `then` function but couldn't find any way to do it